# React JS socket.io-client opens multiple connections

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have a simple React JS app connected to a socket io server. Whenever I open the app in the browser, the client sends new connection request to the server every 5 seconds.

server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('socket id:', socket.id);

})

server.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3001');
})
```

client:

```
import React from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3001');

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>Hi there!</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

logs on the server:

```
socket id: ByXQEMgeVaQ5AGw1AAAA
socket id: 8LzNQsyeYq7GSEvqAAAB
socket id: bbuYEs4kKzjxXuBsAAAC
socket id: vwprv4hnJbRlStG4AAAD
```

I suspect there could be something wrong on my laptop, cause I don't see anything wrong in the code, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add `disconnect` handler event on the socket? Also add a `console.log('connecting')` on the client side before the line `const socket = io('http://localhost:3001');` Maybe you have multiple tabs open? . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend calling connect inside a useEffect and return the disconnect method to be called when the component dismounts.

```
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
  const newSocket = io('http://localhost:3001')
  setSocket(newSocket)

  return socket.disconnect()
}, [])
```

Comment: hi, hope everything is good. i have a question how do i keep a connection always open with not duplication?

Comment: If you put the code in a top level component, App for example it should always keep the connection open.

Comment: Hi thank you for getting back to me, this that the best solution in terms of performance to keep track of messages? or should i just close the socket when user navigates to different screen the send a notification?

Comment: It depends on exactly what you need. If you are only processing message when on a certain screen for example I would put the connect/disconnect code in the top level component of that screen.

Comment: i am creating an in app chat to help users if they have a questions. when the user navigates to the all chats screen, i send an api request to fetch the chats from my db and a socket is opened, then when the user presses on a specific chat a new socket is opened and closed when user leaves specific chat screen and back to all chats screen. when the user leaves the all chat screen to go to any other screen on my app, should i also close that socket ? if not, then i should move that socket to App.js. whats the purpose of having that socket always open?

Comment: That sounds like a sensible structure. I think you don't need to leave the connection always open but, that was your original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248036/discussion-between-kd12345-and-spirift).

Comment: This throws an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'disconnect')"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to wrap the client side socket creation in a useEffect that only runs once? I'm curious to see if the behavior still appears.

```
import React from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3001');

const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3001');
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>Hi there!</div>
  );
}
```

export default App;

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found the root cause, I had a mismatch between my client version and my server version. I updated the client version to v4 and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

When we are connecting the socket, instead of connecting it via a variable we connect it through a state. By doing so we can avoid the problem of multiple connections.

```
//old method
const socket = io.connect("https://example.com")

//to change
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(io.connect("https://example.com"))
```

Comment: Are you then changing the state? Why not use `useRef` if you want a persistent constant value?